# Should I create New Schema Model file for every route OR use already created Schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, architecture, mongoose-schema

Suppose I have a User Schema which has around 30 fields, and other 3 schemas also.

**UserSchema.js**

```
user_schema = new Schema({
    user_id: { type: String},
    .........//30 properties
});
ctrs_schema = new Schema({
    .........10 properties
});
ids_schema = new Schema({
    .........5 properties
});
comments_schema = new Schema({
    .........10 properties
});
```

Now I am writing a route which will change the gender of the user, Now in order to do it I can use **UserSchema.js** but that will load all of the schemas into my route, whereas if I would have created a new file which had only one schema with two fields, then all schemas will not get loaded into the memory for the route.

**UserGenderSchema.js**

```
gender_schema = new Schema({
    user_id: { type: String},
    gender: { type: String}
});
```

I know there are pros and cons of both of the ways

**Pros** -

> I have to edit only in single file if I would have to change something
>   for any field.

**Cons** -

> All Schemas are Loading for all routes which are unnecesary. Memory
>   Wastage.

Will, there be any less memory usage between both of the ways on the threads?

Can anyone Please tell me which architecture will be better or what you are implementing in your project and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's better to keep user related fields in just one schema, cause mongo has been there because of its non-relational structure and it gained its performance by keeping relational structures away, so if you create a schema for each field and then create a reference in each of them to point out to the user they are related to, you are kind of using mongo to build a heavily relational structure and mongo is not good as it should be in this situation, so if later on your application you want to somehow show all the information of the user or try to update multiple fields of user or try to show more information of the user in one of your routes or something, you will end up having some serious performance issues. as a conclusion, the cost of loading all the schema to touch only one field is not as much as the cost of breaking down your data structure.